# ng-repeat in $scope.array of $scope.array of obeject

Tags: angularjs

I want to display these array in a table. One row, then two columns, one row, then two columns etc

The array looks like this:

[image]

How do I run through thess arrays to display the attributs in a table?

The chunking is like this:

```
        function chunk(arr, len) {
        $scope.array = arr;
        var chunks = [],
            i = 0,
            n = $scope.array.length;

        while (i < n) {
            chunks.push($scope.array.slice(i, i += len));
        }

        return chunks;
    }
```

The $scope is created like this:

```
$scope.criteriasearchprofiles = chunk(dataResponse.data, 2);
```

Comment: What's inside the nested object. Can you please expand them and update your screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use nested repeats:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{col}}</td>
</tr>
```

where rows is an array of arrays: `[Array[2], ...]`, and each nested array contains the column objects

Comment: But the name I should refere to is row or? The array dosent have a name in the inner array..

Comment: "rows" is the variable you define in your scope holding the data, "row" is the temp variable that references each item of the array. In your case it would be Array[2], then col references each item in that nested array (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

[image]

I have use this object in more tables, and it work fine. I just wont to modify that code..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your HTML:

```
 <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="criteria in criteriasearchprofiles">
        <td>
            {{criteria.folderName}}  // or any other object attribute
       </td>
       <td>
            {{criteria.selector}} // or any other object attribute
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This only shows the outer array. How do I refer do the inner array when its nameless?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<tr ng-repeat="outercriteriasearchprofiles in criteriasearchprofiles" >
<td ng-repeat="criteriasearchprofiles in outercriteriasearchprofiles | orderBy:'created':true">
{{criteriasearchprofiles.selector}}
</td>
```

Comment: Perhaps upvote or accept his answer to make your 'thanks' somewhat more explicit?